# jQuery not bouncing a div properly in Rails 4 app

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a div bounce when a list element is clicked. This is the code I was using as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Hx65Q/8/

Here's a jsfiddle of what I've got: http://jsfiddle.net/6PWxV/

This is the code I have but it does not seem to work in my Rails app:

home.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ol.rounded-list li").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".bounce-summary").toggle('slide', {
       duration: 1000,
       easing: 'easeOutBounce',
       direction: 'up'
    });
  });
});
```

And the scss:

```
$light-gray-1: #F8F8F8;
$light-gray-2: #EBEBEB;

.bounce-summary {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
ol {
    counter-reset: li;
  list-style: none;
  *list-style: decimal;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 4em;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);

  ol {
    margin: 0 0 0 2em;
  }
}

.rounded-list{
    div {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        padding: .7em .7em .7em 2em;
        *padding: .4em;
        margin: .5em 0;
        background: $light-gray-1;
        color: #444;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: .3em;

        &:hover {
            background: $light-gray-2;
        }
        &:hover:before {
            transform: scaleX(-1);
          -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
          -ms-transform: scaleX(-1); /* IE 9 */
        }
        &.enumerate:before {
            content: counter(li);
          counter-increment: li;
          position: absolute; 
          left: -1.3em;
          top: 50%;
          margin-top: -1em;
          background: #87ceeb;
          height: 2em;
          width: 2em;
          line-height: 1.4em;
          border: .3em solid #fff;
          text-align: center;
          font-weight: bold;
          border-radius: 2em;
          transition: all .3s ease-out;
          -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
        }
        span {
      float: right; 
      background: $light-gray-2;
      padding: 0.4em;
      border-radius: .3em;
      font-size: 0.7em;
    }
    }
}
```

This should be working for ordered lists as such:

```
<ol class="rounded-list">
    <li>
        <div class="enumerate">
            <a target="_blank" href="http://japandailypress.com/more-japanese-restaurants-opening-doors-to-pet-owners-dogs-2546303/">More Japanese restaurants opening doors to pet owners’ dogs</a>
            <span>The Japan Daily Press</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bounce-summary">
            Summary goes in here
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

but alas, it doesn't seem to do anything :\ it doesn't bounce or anything. What am I missing? Is there a way I can let this div drop down below the div but not be counted as a new list element?

Thanks!

Comment: Of course you don't have any error in console, right?!

Comment: can you add your scenario to jsfiddle

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: @j08691 yep I have `//= require jquery` and `//= require jquery_ujs` in my application.js as well as a bundled gem 'jquery-rails' in my Gemfile. It's rather odd...I am using Foundation so maybe Foundation is blocking jQuery?

Comment: @AJ here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/7QFzv/3/  the dropdown works in jsfiddle but not in my rails app for some reason. Also, I'd ideally like to get rid of the number 2 that gets appended to the dropdown, I just want it to show a div, without the numbering.

Comment: what about console errors?

Comment: @AJ Ok looking at the console now it seems that when I click the li element I get the following error: `TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function`

Comment: Ok I found one problem. I was missing the `jquery-easing-rails` gem, which I've now added and included in my asset pipeline. However, the effect still does not seem to work....

Comment: I think this boils down to a problem with Rails not loading the `toggle('slide', {easing: 'easeOutBounce', direction: 'up'}`. As aforementioned, I have included the `jquery-easing-rails` gem and added `//= require jquery.easing` to my application.js so I can't understand why this function wouldn't load.